# VBA Always print specific worksheet on second side

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I have 2 worksheets - A and B.
I am filling rows in worksheet A, then removing empty entries. As a result A can be extended to few pages.
**I want B to always print on second side of A4 when printing A.**
I tried finding solutions, but the only topic I've found has no answers
https://forum.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/45411-double-sided-print-same-page-wanted-on-reverse/

This is my code for printing:

```
Public Sub PrintReport(shift As Integer, dt As Date, ws As Worksheet)
'Open WB wiith worksheets to print
Dim filepath As String
filepath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\AUTOCONTROL.xlsx"
Dim exlApp As Application
Dim FormWorkbook As Workbook
On Error Resume Next
Set exlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set FormWorkbook = exlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filepath, readOnly:=True)
On Error GoTo 0
If FormWorkbook Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Blank report not found. Please contact program author for corrections.")
    Exit Sub
End If
Dim wsForm As Worksheet
If ws.Range("D1").Value = "FARREL 2" Then
    Set wsForm = FormWorkbook.Worksheets("FARREL 2")
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

'POPULATE ROWS IN BLANK REPORT
Dim firstDataRow As Integer
Dim lastDataRow As Integer
Dim lastSourceRow As Integer

lastSourceRow = LastRowWorksheet(ws, "A")
Dim i As Integer
For i = lastSourceRow To 6 Step -20
    If ws.Range("A" & i).MergeArea(1, 1) = dt And ws.Range("B" & i).MergeArea(1, 1) = shift Then
        firstDataRow = i
        lastDataRow = i + 14
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
'PLAN AND BREAKDOWNS FIRST
For i = firstDataRow To lastDataRow
    If (ws.Range("D" & i).Value <> "") And (Not ws.Range("D" & i).Value Like "(POZA*") Then
        Call AddRowDataToForm(ws, i, wsForm)
    End If
Next i
'TRANSFERED COMPOUNDS SECOND
For i = firstDataRow To lastDataRow
    If (ws.Range("D" & i).Value <> "") And (ws.Range("D" & i).Value Like "(POZA*") Then
        Call AddRowDataToForm(ws, i, wsForm)
    End If
Next i

wsForm.Range("L3").Value = dt
wsForm.Range("P3").Value = shift
wsForm.Range("A10").Value = ws.Range("BB" & ActiveCell.MergeArea.row)

'REMOVE EMPTY ROWS IN BLANK REPORT
Call RemoveEmptyRowsFromReport(wsForm)

'PRINT AND CLOSE - 1st page (might be multiple pages)
wsForm.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False
   
'PRINT AND CLOSE - 2nd page (I want it on each reverse, but no iea how)
If ws.Range("D1").Value = "FARREL 2" Then
    Set wsForm = FormWorkbook.Worksheets("AUTOCONTROL FARREL 2")
    wsForm.Range("H3").Value = dt
    wsForm.Range("J3").Value = shift
    wsForm.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False
End If


FormWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

End Sub

Comment: One solution that coms to my mind is to get printing range last row (how?) and copy-paste worksheet in between. Then again set up printing area (next page) from that row to the row of pasted range. This is kind of hard solution if possible. But isn't there any simpler?

Comment: Are you saying that if A is > 1 page, you want printed pg 1 to A pg 2, pg 2 to be B, the pg 3 and on to be A pg 2 and on?

Comment: ... if so, this is not a thing Excel can do natively.   Your thought of copy pasting your data into the required layout is probably the best way to go.  I'd suggest creating a temporary worksheet and copying all data into it.  You can use [range.pagebreak](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pagebreak) to control the pages

Comment: Or dividing worksheet A to multiple worksheets with range.pagebreak? And then copying worksheet B every 2nd worksheet in Workbook. Then printing whole workbook double-sided.